# Is it possible to narrow the type of Value of an object by determining the value of Key with an if statement?

Tags: typescript

First of all, I'm sorry for not giving a good title.
I couldn't find the right words to describe the state, so take a look at the code below.

```js
type MyType = {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: string;
};

const myFunc = <T extends keyof MyType>(obj: MyType, key: T) => {
  const value = obj[key];
  if (key === "b" || key === "c") {
    const stringLength = value.length; // Property 'length' does not exist on type 'MyType[T]'.
    // ...
  }
};
```

After `if (key === "b" || key === "c")`, I thought I could determine that value is a string, but in fact, I get an error.
Can I change the type definition to achieve this behavior?
Or do I need to use Type Guard or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not if the key is a generic type. The issue is that by implementing `myFunc` with a generic, the `obj[key]` will always be of type `MyType[T]` where key is of type `T`, and there is no way to remove the ambiguity of `T` without using force (i.e. `// @ts-ignore`).

However, if you were to remove the generic, in this case, it wasn't really needed since `obj` is always of type `MyType`. So this would look something like...

```js
const myFunc = (obj: MyType, key: keyof MyType) => {
  const outerValue = obj[key];

  if (key === "b" || key === "c") {
    // key is of type 'a' | 'b'
    const innerValue = obj[key];

    console.log(outerValue.length); // this will still throw see below
    console.log(innerValue.length); // this will not throw
  }
}
```

I added the outer and inner value to show that you must access the value of the object **after** the type guard because the type of key when the `outerValue` was declared was `keyof MyType` not `'a' | 'b'` as it is when `innerValue` is declared.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the perfect solution by any means and I'm sure the gurus here can find a better way, but, you could try:

```
type aType = { key: 'a', a: number; };
type bType = { key: 'b', b: string; };
type cType = { key: 'c', c: string; };

type MyType = aType | bType | cType;


const myFunc = (obj: MyType) => {

  if (obj.key === 'a') {
    const numberValue = obj.a;
  } if (obj.key === 'b') {
    const stringLength = obj.b.length;

  } if (obj.key === 'c') {
    const stringLength = obj.c.length;
  } else {
    throw new Error('invalid key');

  }

};

myFunc({ key: 'a', a: 1 });
```